# Tungsten Replicator 4.0 Installation

Tags: mysql, tungsten-replicator

I am trying to install Tungsten Replicator 4.0 version for Mysql 5.7. I have used binary installation(tar.gz file installation) for Mysql 5.7 and exported path in `bash_profile`.

`./tools/tmp install` command got executed successfully but services both master and slave are offline. We are getting below error for service status command.

```
[tungsten@beta-388 tungsten-replicator-4.0.0-18]$ /opt/continuent//tungsten/tungsten-replicator/bin/trepctl services

Processing services command...

NAME              VALUE
----              -----
appliedLastSeqno: -1
appliedLatency  : -1.0
role            : master
serviceName     : beta182_183
serviceType     : unknown
started         : true
state           : OFFLINE:ERROR

NAME              VALUE
----              -----
**appliedLastSeqno**:**** **Unknown**
**appliedLatency  **:**** **Unknown**
**role**            **:** **Unknown**
serviceName     : beta183_182
serviceType     : Unknown
started         : false
state           : Unknown

Finished services command...
```

```
[tungsten@beta-388 tungsten-replicator-4.0.0-18]$ /opt/continuent//tungsten/tungsten-replicator/bin/trepctl -service beta182_183 status

Processing status command...

NAME                     VALUE
----                     -----
appliedLastEventId     : NONE
appliedLastSeqno       : -1
appliedLatency         : -1.0
autoRecoveryEnabled    : true
autoRecoveryTotal      : 0
channels               : -1
clusterName            : beta182_183
currentEventId         : NONE
currentTimeMillis      : 1579684465335
dataServerHost         : beta-388.panterranetworks.net
extensions             :
host                   : beta-388.panterranetworks.net
latestEpochNumber      : -1
masterConnectUri       : thls://localhost:/
masterListenUri        : thls://beta-388.panterranetworks.net:12120/
maximumStoredSeqNo     : -1
minimumStoredSeqNo     : -1
offlineRequests        : NONE
pendingError           : Replicator unable to go online due to error
pendingErrorCode       : NONE
pendingErrorEventId    : NONE
pendingErrorSeqno      : -1
pendingExceptionMessage: **Unable to prepare plugin: class name=com.continuent.tungsten.replicator.thl.THL message=[Error while attempting to acquire file lock: /opt/continuent/thl/beta182_183/disklog.lck]**
pipelineSource         : UNKNOWN
relativeLatency        : -1.0
resourcePrecedence     : 99
rmiPort                : 10110
role                   : master
seqnoType              : java.lang.Long
serviceName            : beta182_183
serviceType            : unknown
simpleServiceName      : beta182_183
siteName               : default
sourceId               : beta-388.panterranetworks.net
state                  : OFFLINE:ERROR
timeInStateSeconds     : 15.744
timezone               : GMT
transitioningTo        :
uptimeSeconds          : 15.931
useSSLConnection       : true
version                : Tungsten Replicator 4.0.0 build 18

Finished status command...
```

Can anyone please share how to resolve the error? I have tried multiple times with giving all permissions to the file and also uninstalled and reinstalled the tungsten.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql version 5.7 is not support tungsten version 4.0, 
https://docs.continuent.com/tungsten-replicator-4.0/introduction.html

Shared your config replicator!